# Does a chemical reaction depends on the amount of reactants?

Tags: thermodynamics, stoichiometry

A chemical reaction depends on many things like the temperature, pressure etc. i wanted to ask if It also depends on the amount of reactants for example;

If A + B gives C and assuming this equation is balanced, all other conditions are same but less amount of B is there so will the same reaction occur where B will be the limiting reagent and less amount of C will be produced or to compensate the lesser availability of B another product will be formed  like it happens in case of incomplete combustion of Carbon?

If yes then doesn't the concept of Stoichiometry kind of fails?

If reading this question makes you feel angry at how stupid i am please forgive me

Comment: Do you mean *ratio* of reactants, or *amount* of reactants? The *amount* could be significant **if** one takes the environment into account. For example, mixing one mg of glycerol and "mixed acids", without cooling, might produce a few mg of nitroglycerin, but mixing in 1,000 kg with mixed acids without cooling would produce various nitrogen oxides, CO2, and a large hole in the ground.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik you forgot water vapor maybe?

Comment: @OscarLanzi, yes, and some other products. Perhaps I should have picked a simpler example -- making a little NI3, or drying a kg of it.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of stoichiometry says that molecular entities mutually react in ratio of small integer numbers.

That applies on particular reactions.

It does not say there cannot be different preferred reactions for different reagent ratios.

E.g. two elements may form several binary compounds and the product ratio is closely related to the molar ratio of reagents.

But each of such reactions follows the stoichiometric requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The example you use doesn't show that the laws of stoichiometry *fail*, it merely shows that the equations you write have to consider all the components both before and after the reaction.

In the simplest case of A + B -> C the equation is fine if the amounts of A and B are equal. If side reactions are unimportant but you have a deficit of B, you might think that the equation A + B -> C is no longer true; but, in reality, the correct equation (obeying the laws) would be 2A + B -> C + A (with half the starting amount of A unreacted). The laws hold but only if you count *all* the components before and after the reaction.

In cases where observing *all* the products or reactants is hard, chemists usually assume the laws hold (and maybe find better ways to measure them to check as early chemists did to understand what "burning" meant when they burned things and carefully measured the mass of both solid products and the emitted gases).